# using regular expression to get digit before $ sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to get digits in a string occurring before dollar sign.

For example "black/yellow/silver 14 $110.00"

the string is found with jquery like this - $('div').attr('value') - and I am trying to fetch '14' using .match but couldn't find a way to start from $ sign and go backward to the '14'

This is probably very basic, thanks very much for advice.

Comment: Is there just one group of numbers before the dollar? Just use `/\d+/` and get the first match.

Comment: Will the string always be formatted like that?  I.e., "TEXT/TEXT/TEXT ## $###.##"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var string = "black/yellow/silver 14 $110.00";
var digits = string.match(/(\d+)\s+\$/)[1]
```

Comment: I might use `\s*` instead to be slightly more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Using lookahead:

```
s = "black/yellow/silver 14 $110.00";
m = s.match(/\d+(?= *\$)/);
//=> ["14"]
```

Comment: I would suggest [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) instead of `match`, assuming a single value is wanted and not an array.

Comment: @Phrogz: `exec()` also returns a result array.